# SMTP-Server Not recieving emails

Tags: node.js, email, smtp

I am using [smtp-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smtp-server) and I have followed examples in the documentation. When I run my smtp-server script (node ./mail-server.js) there are no errors but it doesn't receive mail. I am using gmail and sending to user@ I have port forwarded the port I am listening on as well.

```
var SMTPServer = require('smtp-server').SMTPServer;
const server = new SMTPServer({
    secure: false,
    disabledCommands: ['AUTH', 'STARTTLS'],
    onData: (stream, session, callback) => {
        stream.pipe(process.stdout); // print message to console
        stream.on('end', callback);
    }
});

server.on('error', (err) =>{
    console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
});

server.listen(25);
```

Comment: Is your domain registered with the global DNS servers so that google can route the mail to your IP?

Comment: At first they weren't @PeterVC I was using my external ip rather than a domain. Then i switched to using No-Ip.com which registers domains and points them to your ip.

Comment: Have you confirmed its a Node problem and not a network or GMail problem?  Can you telnet to your mail server?

Comment: No @PeterVC, it is run on my local machine. I did move it to a VPS to which I can SSH to and had the same results though. I am not sure how I would test if it were a network or GMail problem.

Comment: You could run a simple HTTP server to test if the outside world can see it.  What happens when you try to telnet to it?

Comment: I have a web server running on it already and it works fine. I've done some more digging and now I believe it might be a firewall issue on my side. I've put it on an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS VPS and I can netcat to port 25 with localhost but not with the ip of the VPS I also cannot Telnet to it and all portcheckers say port 25 is closed.

Comment: After posting that I poked around some more now that I knew it was a networking or firewall issue (which I am decent at troubleshooting) I figured out that you have to bind to the IP you are using in the smtp server. By not specifying an ip it uses localhost meaning the mail server was closed to public! I changed the IP to the VPS's IP and I could telnet to it fine! Thanks for the help, @PeterVC